# Passing child class (of the original's class function arg) as arg to overridden function

Tags: php-7.1

I've built a package that (simply said for this post) holds a User model class and a UserFormatter class. I have an application that loads this package in order to add some custom work.

What I like to do in my custom application is to let the UserFormatter return an additional key in it's array.

Let me start off with showing some code to understand my 'issue':

Package code:

```
class User
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $email;
}

class UserFormatter
{
    public static function format(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

Application code (used for overriding some package code):

```
class UserExt extends User
{
    protected $role;
}

class UserFormatterExt extends UserFormatter
{
    public static function format(UserExt $user)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'role'  => $user->role,
        ];
    }
}
```

This does not work as I thought it would. PHP warns me about the arg in the overridden format function. The typehint doesn't match (User <> UserExt) Although the UserExt is a child class of User.

I'm wondering what would be the best solution to solve my issue?

Some various options I have in mind:

- Don't extend UserFormatter but then I'd lose some functionality in the UserFormatter class, that I'd like to use and I would have to copy-paste that code (against DRY)
- Remove the typehint for the arg of the format function and check if the incoming arg is an-instance-of ..
- **Or is there a nicer solution**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't extend `UserFormatter` but instead call a `UserFormatter::format` inside your custom UserFormatter and then merge the additional data into the returned array.

```
class UserFormatterExt
{
    public static function format(UserExt $user)
    {
        $formattedUser = UserFormatter::format($user);
        $formattedUser['role'] = $user->role;
        return $formattedUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm .. I like your suggestion!

Comment: @mattyh88 The reason why you cannot extend and make the argumetn more specific is in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

UserFormatterExt if it extends UserFormatter must provide the same behavior, which means the format method must work with an User object, by specifing a more specific object you make the behavior different. Therefore in this case composition is probably the better option compared to inheritance.